# Arrowheads from VectorPlot3D not rendering when exported as STL

Tags: vector, stl-format

I am trying to export VectorPlot3D output to an STL file (or any 3D
format). My goal is to allow my students to use Augmented Reality to
better visualize the vector field. However, when I export to STL the
arrowheads do not render. A tube representing the vector renders, but
no indication of the direction of the vectors. My code is below:

```
VF = VectorPlot3D[{1, 0, z}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
  VectorScale -> Automatic, VectorMarkers -> "Arrow3D"]
Export["VectorField.stl", VF]
```

Comment: My experience is that only solids render in STL. Lines, points, and similar one-dimensional or two-dimensional artifacts do not render. You might want to try creating cones at the end of tubes.

Comment: Could that be done with VectorPlot3D or something like it, or do I have to create each vector individually (or write a program to do so)?

Comment: I would convert the arrows into `Tube[]`s and `Cone[]`s, display them with `Graphics3D[]` and `Export[]` the result if you like it.